# How to check if a rails session is already loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to check if a rails session is already loaded. If I trace the session I get this:

```
Session: #<Rack::Session::Abstract::SessionHash:0x8e3e not yet loaded>
```

Comment: Ok, session.loaded? did it. How obvious.

Comment: rails has the method session.loaded?

Comment: You should answer you own question (thats not a comment), that way it gets closed. Now the questions keeps being open (as in 0 answers). Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

session.loaded? does the trick.

Comment: `session.loaded? = true` means someone has logged in currently? Can it serve like `!current_user.nil?`